# Environment dependent values in wso2 esb best option

Tags: wso2-esb

Imagine that you have a parameter used in a wso2 esb sequence that you need has a different value in development than in producction environment.
    I use to manage this in filesystem configuration files managed with chef, puppet or ansible.
    In WSO2 I think I can't user registry to store environment dependent values because info is stored in a database and I can't manage registry configuration whit ansible.
    How do you use to solve this situations in WSO2 ESB?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is using system variables. You can access the system variables from the script mediator within proxy/sequences/api configurations in ESB mediation flows.

```
<script language="js">mc.setProperty("file.separator",java.lang.System.getProperty("file.separator"));</script>
<log level="custom">
   <property name="file.separator" expression="get-property('file.separator')"/>
</log>
```

Here "file.separator" is read from the system properties and set to message context. Then you can use it in other subsequent mediators.

You can give the system properties at the server start time as follows

```
-Dsystem.property.name=system.property.value
```

You can place these in wso2server.sh file or give them as command line arguments when starting the server.

Answer (score 0):

I'm interested in this as well, I manage a kind of hack with ansible. I've a "default" registry project containing some variables. I use ansible to extract it and replace the variable with the actual values for each environment. It's tricky but working if you do not have to much variables.

```
- name: "Extract Regitry project to temp folder"
  unarchive:
    src: "/tmp/{{ registry.name }}_{{ registry.version }}.car"
    dest: "/tmp/{{ registry.name }}_{{ registry.version }}"
    remote_src: yes

- name: "Set Sample Host"
  copy:
    content: "sample.api.url"
    dest: "/tmp/{{ registry.name }}_{{ registry.version }}/sample_host_{{ registry.version }}/resources/sample_host"
  no_log: true

- name: "Set Sample Password"
  copy:
    content: "{{ wso2.api.pwd }}"
    dest: "/tmp/{{ registry.name }}_{{ registry.version }}/sample_api_pwd_{{ registry.version }}/resources/sample_api_pwd"
  no_log: true

- name: "Package registry project"
  archive:
    path:
      - "/tmp/{{ registry.name }}_{{ registry.version }}/*"
      - "/tmp/{{ registry.name }}_{{ registry.version }}/*.xml"
    dest: "{{ wso2ei_path }}/repository/deployment/server/carbonapps/{{ registry.name }}.car"
    format: zip
    owner: "{{ wso2_user }}"
```

If you have a better approach I'd like to adapt as well :)

Answer (score 0):

based on my experience I would recommend integrate Consul (https://www.consul.io/) with WSO2 ESB. Consul allows registration, configuration and discovery services in infrastructures. Basically WSO2 ESB can consume the REST apis Consul to obtain endpoints.